# WebServiceCallout.Invoke() Method gives Issues in Namespace

Tags: soap-api, integration, xml

Can Anyone Help me out in following case :

For multiple namespaces callout feature is expecting second element to be in same name space as highest level element. In my wsdl, I have three namespaces in total, say namespace1, namespace2, and namespace3. The following will be valid soap message for the service I am calling.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<env:Header/>

<env:Body>

<Request xmlns="namespace1">

<RequestElement1 xmlns="namespace2>

<Data1>Data1</Data1>

<Data2>Data2</Data2>

</RequestElement1>

</Request> 

</env:Body>

</env:Envelope>
```

But Sales force generates the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<env:Header/>

<env:Body>

<Request xmlns="namespace1">

<RequestElement1>

<Data1 xmlns="namespace2">Data1</Data1>

<Data2 xmlns="namespace2">Data2</Data2>

</RequestElement1>

</Request> 

</env:Body>

</env:Envelope>
```

My WSDL is valid and I am able make calls from any other system.

> UPDATED :  I can find an interesting issue logged against the same
>   issue :
>   https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4vjAAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two ways to achieve this
1) Either create a XML and send request using rest.
2) ask the vendor to change and convert it to single namespace XML.

Please Vote the above idea so that this issue can be resolved

Comment: Himanshu do not ask for upvoting in your answers on this site. It is against our usual standards though it is not that clear in the answering and other guidelines. The principle is that good answers will get accepted and upvoted by the community without  prompting. see - http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/whats-acceptable-accept-answer-solicitation-revisited/2274#2274

Comment: Hello Dave, 
As you can see that difference between Question and answer date and I do not  wanted to keep this questions unanswered.

Comment: Himanshu nothing wrong with answering your own question and yes fine to ask to upvote an idea on the SF site. Sorry I misread that part of your answer.